# Setting up 20TB storage: use normal file system or hadoop

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I am a young researcher and plan to buy a computing server for (maybe "big") data analysis. The server will have a 20TB hard disk space. My current question is should I use normal linux file system or hadoop hdfs as the system. Would anybody kindly explain the pros and cons on these two choices?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is define your IO requirements.  Only *after* you've done that can you even ask what solution best fits your needs.

Comment: I am not sure... Maybe I will start with storing lots of small files once and read them a few times a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really makes no sense to have HDFS over a single node (one server). HDFS is all about *distributing* data so that compute tasks run close to the data, and having redundant copies of the data to be able to tolerate hardware failures. A single node will offer not a single HDFS benefit. If you have a *cluster* of machines (eg. 10 servers) then yes, you can ask this question. As is, HDFS is not an option.

Comment: Understood. One last question: will HDFS be more efficient in storing data? (In "many small document" and "a few big document" cases)

Comment: HDFS cannot be more efficient than the underlying file system. HDFS will multiply any document by the replication factor (usually 3x) and will split large documents into small blocks. So, whatever the efficiency of the underlying file system is, HDFS running above it will be, at best, the same, but often will be worse.